# Swagger definition for array of query params with multiple formats

Tags: openapi

I'm using swagger to define my API and I have an endpoint that accepts an array of parameters in both formats:

- `/users?id=3&id=4&id=5`
- `/users?id=3,4,5`

To define one or the other, I need to set the "explode" property to either true or false, but I need both and Im struggling to find the correct way to define it.

Comment: Great question. I recommend asking this in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Comment: I guess this is not supported and you'd have to use a single preferred/default format (e.g. `explode: false`) but you could mention both formats in the parameter `description`. But maybe OpenAPI maintainers could suggest a better solution.